# Quill BlockEmbed with editable span

Tags: javascript, svelte, quill

I am trying to create a BlockEmbed where the span can be edited (as part of a more complex use case). Why isn't the event handler for the span being fired. I assume something else is blocking it? Any ideas?

```js
import Quill from 'quill';

const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

class EditBlot extends BlockEmbed {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();
    let label = document.createElement('span');
    label.contentEditable = 'true';
    label.innerText = value.text;
    node.appendChild(label);

    label.addEventListener("input", () => {
      console.log('input');
      value.text = label.innerText;
      node.setAttribute('data-value', JSON.stringify(value));
    }, false);

    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data-value'));
  }
}

EditBlot.blotName = 'edit';
EditBlot.tagName = 'div';

export default EditBlot;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using MutationObserver. (class is somewhat modified to be a Todo, as I was experimenting with adding multiple editable items)

```js
import Quill from 'quill';

const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

class TodoBlot extends BlockEmbed {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.classList.add('ql-todo-item');

    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.checked = value.checked;
    checkbox.setAttribute('data-action', 'check');

    let label = document.createElement('span');
    label.contentEditable = 'true';
    label.classList.add('ql-todo-label');
    label.innerText = value.text;
    label.setAttribute('data-action', 'edit');

    node.appendChild(checkbox);
    node.appendChild(label);

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      value.checked = checkbox.checked;
      node.setAttribute('data-checked', value.checked);
    });

    let observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
      for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
          value.text = label.textContent;
          node.setAttribute('data-text', value.text);
        }
      }
    });
    observer.observe(label, { characterData: true, subtree: true });

    node.setAttribute('data-checked', value.checked);
    node.setAttribute('data-text', value.text);
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    let checked = node.getAttribute('data-checked') === 'true';
    let text = node.getAttribute('data-text') || '';
    return { checked, text };
  }
}

TodoBlot.blotName = 'todo';
TodoBlot.tagName = 'div';

export default TodoBlot;
```